# How to change font/number/bullet format for the whole list

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

Let's look at a sample word 2010 file [here](http://db.tt/Fl9J1Cc).

In this file you can see that the first group of text has their indent modified. The 2nd, 3rd group keep their default format.

I want to apply the changed I've made in the group 1st so group 2nd and 3rd and for the new group I'm going to add instead of recieving the default indent. How can I do that?

ps.

Currently what I have to do is quite boring: Copy group 1 and paste to create new group to get the formatted, then remove the old text, adding new text :(

I'm thinking of using style but really failed to create style for the list with multiple levels like this.

Answer (score 0):

Highlight the first group, click the [Format Painter](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/help/quickly-copy-formatting-with-the-format-painter-HA001054892.aspx) button on the Home tab of the Ribbon, and select the rest of the groups.  Press `ESC` when you're done.

Comment: I don't think so. Your suggestion only works for 1st level of the list; other-than-1st level will all become 1st which is not what I need.